# Java Slick2d particles error

Tags: java, slick

When i run the game particles crash the game, im not sure what am i doing wrong because the program doesnt tell me. But i know particles are causing this , if i remove the code in update code at bottom, the runnable jar works fine.

Particle class : http://pastebin.com/ATLN6qzR

Particle manager : http://pastebin.com/vAk1nwmi

Slick 2d docmentation : http://www.slick2d.org/javadoc/

It says error is here where the for starts

```
public void update(int delta){

    for (Particle o: particleList) {
        if(o.emitter.completed() == true){
            particleList.remove(o); 
        }
        else{
            o.system.update(delta);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Debugging is almost always too localised to be useful to anyone else. Could you condense the problem further than "I don't know what's happening, but here's all my code"?

Comment: i edited the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're not seeing this problem in the debug version.

```
for (Particle o: particleList) {
    if(o.emitter.completed() == true){
        particleList.remove(o); 
    }
```

Attempting to remove an item from a list while iterating through that list will give you a concurrency exception.

Instead of `particleList.remove(o);` add the item to remove list. Then after your for each loop, loop through the remove list and use the `particleList.remove(o);` call. Then clear your remove list.

Like this:

```
ArrayList<Particle> toRemove = new ArrayList<Particle>();
for (Particle o: particleList) {
    if(o.emitter.completed() == true)
        toRemove.add(o);
    else
        o.system.update(delta);
}

//remove finished particles
for (Particle o: toRemove) {
    particleList.remove(o);
}
toRemove.clear();
```

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Alternatively you can use an Iterator http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Comment: If i understand correctly i should make another list and save the objects that need removing , then i loop trough remove list and compare with with particle list and remove from particle list.

Comment: I've updated the answer with a direct solution. There's no "compare with the particle list". Just remove.

Comment: thanks , I didn't know it could automaticaly locate the object